# macro to copy formula down if adjacent cell not blank

Tags: excel, vba

Okay folks, I have this simple table below and I am trying to calculate a macro vba formula in column G as long as column c has a value. All the info in the spreadsheet is already pulled in from a previous macro.  Here is what I have....

[image: 1]

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    
    Dim x As Long
    
    x = CLng((d2 + e2) / c2)
    
    
    For Each r In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("C:C"))
        If r.Value <> "" Then
         r.Offset(1, 5).Value = x
    
        End If
    Next r

    
End Sub
```

Comment: test the code in my answer below and let me know if it works like you intended

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, it will loop through Column C (until last row with value in it), and will calculate your formula with the relevant parameters of that row in Column G.

**Note**: your formula of `(D+E)/C` will give you small values, as `C` has high values. If that's the formula you want to use, than you need to change the output from `Long` to `Double` to show the numbers after the `0.`.

### Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

' Macro1    
Dim r As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

' modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' find last row with data in Column C ("Salary")
    LastRow = .Cells(.rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each r In .Range("C2:C" & LastRow)
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            r.Offset(0, 4).Value = CDbl((Range("D" & r.Row).Value + Range("E" & r.Row).Value) / r.Value)
        End If
    Next r        
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Range("G2:G" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(C2,"", "",B2)"
```

Counts rows in column C, if not empty, fills in Concatenation formula that you can change to your formula.

Answer (score -1):

You refer to cells as Range("D2") etc rather than just d2.